# duplicating/replicating only specific rows in a data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have data acording to uniue id and sorted on date of visit. Some people have multiple visits. Data is in the long format sorted by visit. I only want to replicate a row of the last visit of each person. How does one replicate only specific rows in a data frame?

```
id  visit             glucose
1     12 Jan 2015      12
1      3 Feb 2015       8
2      1 Feb 2015       13
3      12 Jan 2015      7 
3      4 Feb 2015       13
3      1  March 2015    8
```

Comment: You mean keeping the last date of each id? Like `df[duplicated(df$id),]`?

Answer (score 1):

If we need to duplicate the last row based on the 'visit' for each 'id', we can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `order` by 'id', and 'visit', grouped by 'id', we replicate the last row (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(id, as.Date(visit, "%d %b %Y")), .SD[c(seq_len(.N), .N)], by = id]
#    id         visit glucose
#1:  1   12 Jan 2015      12
#2:  1    3 Feb 2015       8
#3:  1    3 Feb 2015       8
#4:  2    1 Feb 2015      13
#5:  2    1 Feb 2015      13
#6:  3   12 Jan 2015       7
#7:  3    4 Feb 2015      13
#8:  3 1  March 2015       8
#9:  3 1  March 2015       8
```

---

If we want only the last row for each 'id'

```
setDT(df1)[order(id, as.Date(visit, "%d %b %Y")), .SD[.N], id]
```

Comment: tab<-setDT(t)[order(id, as.Date(dcdate)), .SD[c(seq_len(.N), .N)], by = id] worked as the file was imported from Excel so dates were ok